# How to manage individual job queues while only allowing 1 job to run at a time with rxjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, queue, cancellation

I am trying to make a slightly complex queue system in rxjs as follows:

- any user can request a title at any time as long as they have no request or timeout pending
- any user with a title can cancel their timeout
- titles are hold only for 30 seconds tops
- a title can be hold only by one user at any time
- multiple titles can be hold by a user once at the same time
- titles are delivered when nobody else is using them

  - if a title is not being used is delivered immediately when asked for
  - if a title is in use is delivered at the moment the current user gives it back or their time runs out

```js
import {
  Subject,
  groupBy,
  mergeMap,
  switchMap,
  delayWhen,
  timer,
  takeUntil,
  share,
} from "rxjs";

type Snowflake = string;

enum Title {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
}

const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

// This is an external function, cannot modify
const startTitleReq = (item: { title: Title; user: Snowflake }) => {
  console.log(`Starting request for ${item.user}, requested ${item.title}`);

  // Can take longer in reality
  return sleep(10_000).then(() => ({ success: true }));
};

const queue = new Subject<{ title: Title; user: Snowflake }>();
const cancel = new Subject();

queue
  .pipe(
    groupBy((item) => item.title),
    mergeMap((group$) =>
      group$.pipe(
        switchMap((item) => startTitleReq(item)),
        delayWhen((result) =>
          timer(result.success ? 10_000 : 0).pipe(takeUntil(cancel))
        )
      )
    ),
    share()
  )
  .subscribe(({ success }) => {
    console.log({ success });
  });

queue.next({ user: "1", title: Title.A });
queue.next({ user: "2", title: Title.A });
queue.next({ user: "3", title: Title.B });
```

So the expected results would be:

```js
queue.next({ user: "1", title: Title.A }); // 1, success log after 10 seconds
queue.next({ user: "2", title: Title.A }); // 3, success log after 40 seconds
queue.next({ user: "3", title: Title.B }); // 2, success log after 20 seconds
```

Now let's say this were the start:

```js
queue.next({ user: "1", title: Title.A }); // 1, success log after 10 seconds

// After 5 seconds..
cancel.next();

queue.next({ user: "2", title: Title.A }); // 2, success log after 25 seconds
```

[Link to playgound](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vybotx?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Good thinking with the mocks and trying to simplify the issue to be as minimal as possible.

I've taken a pick at what I think is what you want:

```js
const request$$ = new Subject<string>();

const queue$ = request$$.pipe(
  concatMap((title) =>
    getTitle(title).pipe(
      map((_) => ({ title, success: true })),
      timeout(30_000),
      catchError((e) => {
        return of({ title, success: false });
      })
    )
  )
);
```

When I give a go with a random delay for the `getTitle` method, here's what we get:

*(Note that I've lowered down the timeout to 5s instead of 30 and made the random delay go between 1 and 10s)*

```
Starting request for title Title 0 (delay 5006)
{title: "Title 0", success: false}

Starting request for title Title 1 (delay 9117)
{title: "Title 1", success: false}

Starting request for title Title 2 (delay 1160)
{title: "Title 2", success: true}

Starting request for title Title 3 (delay 1521)
{title: "Title 3", success: true}

Starting request for title Title 4 (delay 5109)
{title: "Title 4", success: false}

Starting request for title Title 5 (delay 8671)
{title: "Title 5", success: false}

Starting request for title Title 6 (delay 6618)
{title: "Title 6", success: false}

Starting request for title Title 7 (delay 3804)
{title: "Title 7", success: true}

Starting request for title Title 8 (delay 2827)
{title: "Title 8", success: true}

Starting request for title Title 9 (delay 6142)
{title: "Title 9", success: false}
```

Here's the [live demo with the mocks](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bkmluq?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).

---

**EDIT:** Based on the comments it looks like I did not understood the issue the first time. Here's the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qbq4ka?file=index.ts) for my second take at it.

Bulk of the code:

```
const queue$$ = new Subject<{ title: Title; user: Snowflake }>();
const cancel$$ = new Subject<void>();

const queue$ = queue$$.pipe(
  concatMap((item) =>
    startTitleReq(item).pipe(
      timeout(10_000),
      catchError(() => {
        return of({ success: false });
      }),
      takeUntil(cancel$$)
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for this! However `success` is only an indication for the user to see if the title request was succesful, internally it would be used to start a timer so the user gets to keep the title for 30 seconds or they can cancel the timer to allow the next one in their queue to get a title. I tried to come up with something closer to this story but I can't get it to run: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vybotx?file=index.ts

Comment: I did get it to run now, but the timer doesn't work as expected

Comment: I'm completely lost. Could you edit your original post to make it a lot simpler and stay focused on the stream problem? We don't need to talk about the websockets etc. If you describe it as a purely rxjs challenge with expected behavior that'd be a lot simpler to understand and help you. A marble diagram would be welcome, otherwise just write for a given set of inputs the expected outputs (including the time at which it should be happening)

Comment: Thanks! Reading your code I'm still confused. Why did you use `groupBy`? Do you want to queue them no questions asked or do you want to queue by group of the same title? In other words, are you trying to have 1 global queue that'll wait X s for an observable to resolve otherwise move on to next and also that same observable can be cancelled manually to move on earlier to the next one?

Comment: Had another go based on what I thought. Please have a look at my post, made an edit at the bottom.

Comment: Your snippet is pretty close to what's ideal. I grouped them because let's say User 2 requests title B, they would only have to wait for User 1's `startTitleReq` to finish rather than waiting out the 10 seconds or for that user to cancel before the 10 seconds. So you could say there 1 global queue to ensure the app only runs 1 `startTitleReq` at a time, and title queues where users have to wait for both `startTitleReq` and the previous user's timeout / cancellation

Comment: `timeout` should only happen when `startTitleReq` was succesful. It essentially means "you got your title for 10 seconds, either cancel to allow the next person in your queue to get it or lose it after 10 seconds". Users requesting a different title shouldn't want to wait out this timeout, just `startTitleReq`. Users requesting a different title don't deal with the timeout

Comment: Well I'm completely lost again. Maybe try to think of a way to explain this in a very generic and well detailed way. Otherwise sorry not sure to help more than this

Comment: I have edited the question to add the story at the start

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That said, I don't know if it's just me but I still don't understand... Maybe try to abstract your "title" context and try to explain differently. I feel like we're going round a bit, I don't mind telling you that I don't understand until I do so if you really want an answer bear with me. As I said, try to really really abstract and explain clearly the issue

Comment: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hvtq91?devtoolsheight=60&file=tasks.todo,index.ts) is a working example. Only problem being that `setTitle` calls a function to fetch it which takes some time and returns if it was succesful. Only if it was it should set the title and I'd want to return the success status to the calling side as well. I couldn't figure out how to achieve that

Comment: I think I will turn it into a separate question, thanks though!